# Cakephp complex query with combination of conditions

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

i have some conditions in cakephp. for example, i need to check a table with status = 1, from = 'some city', age = 35 and language = 'english'. I need to get the data from table with all conditions like, status and from, status and age, status and language, status and from and age. for all combination of the condition i need to get the records. Please help to resolve this issue. I'm stuck in this for 2 days. Thanks in advance. I tried with below query

```
        if(!empty($search_terms['from'])){
            $conditions[] = array('location'=>$search_terms['from']);
        }
        if(!empty($search_terms['type'])){
            $conditions[] = array('maid_type'=>$search_terms['type']);
        }

        if(!empty($search_terms['age'])){
            if (strpos($search_terms['age'],'-') !== false) {
                $age_value = explode("-",$search_terms['age']);
                $conditions[] = array('AND'=>array(
                                            array('age <=' =>$age_value[0]),
                                            array('age >=' =>$age_value[1])));
            }

        }   

        if(!empty($search_terms['salary'])){
            if (strpos($search_terms['salary'],'-') !== false) {
                $salary_value = explode("-",$search_terms['salary']);
                $conditions[] = array('AND'=>array(
                                            array('salary >=' =>$salary_value[0]),
                                            array('salary <=' =>$salary_value[1])));
            }else{
                if (strpos($search_terms['salary'],'below') !== false){
                    $salary_value = filter_var($search_terms['salary'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                    $conditions[] = array('salary < '=> $salary_value);
                }elseif(strpos($search_terms['salary'],'upper') !== false){
                    $salary_value = filter_var($search_terms['salary'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
                    $conditions[] = array('salary > '=> $salary_value);
                }
            }

        }                               

        if(!empty($search_terms['maritial'])){
            $conditions[] = array('maritial_status'=>$search_terms['maritial']);
        }                   

        if(!empty($search_terms['education'])){
            $conditions[] = array('education'=>$search_terms['education']);
        }                   

        if(!empty($search_terms['relegion'])){
            $conditions[] = array('relegion'=>$search_terms['relegion']);
        }       

        if(!empty($search_terms['duty_optn'])){
            foreach($search_terms['duty_optn'] as $duty_opn){
                $conditions[] = array('FIND_IN_SET(\''. $duty_opn .'\',maid_duty)');
            }
        }           

        if(!empty($search_terms['keyword'])){
            $conditions[] = array('code LIKE' => '%'.$search_terms['keyword'].'%');
        }   
    }


    $all_maids = $this->Maid->find('all',array('conditions'=>$conditions);
```

Im getting the below conditions

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [location] => indonesia
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [maid_type] => ex-singapore
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [AND] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [age <=] => 41
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [age >=] => 50
                        )

                )

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [AND] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [salary >=] => 400
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [salary <=] => 500
                        )

                )

        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [maritial_status] => married
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [education] => high_school
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [relegion] => buddhist
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [0] => FIND_IN_SET('children_care',maid_duty)
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [0] => FIND_IN_SET('elderly_care',maid_duty)
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [0] => FIND_IN_SET('care_for_disabled',maid_duty)
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [code LIKE] => %code 3%
        )

)
```

Comment: can you show your query

Comment: SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE STATUS = 1 AND AGE = 35 AND LANGUAGE = 'english'.  What is the problem? ;)

Comment: @vikramsharma the conditions are dynamic. i ll post my query

Comment: what output you have in print_r($conditions)

Comment: $all_maids = $this->Maid->find('all',array('conditions'=>array($conditions));

Comment: @vikramsharma just a min

Comment: @vikramsharma i updated with the conditions array

Comment: you are using only one table or more then one if you are using more then one table then you first load the model

Comment: "%$search_terms['keyword']%"

Comment: i think you are using only table because you only find from one table called Maid

Comment: @vikramsharma im using only one table. I'm just asking the idea to get all the possible conditions. there is no issue.

Comment: @vikramsharma i wnat like this. If A,B,C means i want AB,AC,ABC. i want like this without duplicate value

Comment: You have up to eight conditions (from, type, age, etc.). It is unclear what the acceptable combinations of conditions are. Is it a simple **OR** between conditions?  If it is not, then you need to create a [Truth table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truth_table) for all conditions and a final column representing if you want the result. I suggest you delete this question, and write a new one with the truth table.

Answer (score 0):

plz create your array in below format :

Array
(
        ['location'] => 'indonesia',
        ['maid_type'] => 'ex-singapore',
        ['age <='] => 41,
        ['age >='] => 50,
        ['salary >='] => 400,
        ['salary <='] => 500,
        ['maritial_status'] => 'married',
        ['education'] => 'high_school',
            ['relegion'] => 'buddhist',
        [0] => FIND_IN_SET('children_care',maid_duty),
        [1] => FIND_IN_SET('elderly_care',maid_duty),
        [2] => FIND_IN_SET('care_for_disabled',maid_duty),
        ['code LIKE'] => '%code 3%'
)